# Elasticsearch: Exclude filter clause from scoring

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a filter clause deep inside a query clause but I think it doesn't make sense to calculate a score for the filter clause. How can I take this filter clause out? Would this improve performance?

```
{
   "size" : 30,
   "sort" : [
      {
         "_score" : {
            "order" : "desc"
         }
      }
   ],

   "query" : {
      "function_score" : {
         "score_mode" : "sum",
         "boost_mode" : "sum",
         "functions" : [
            {
              ...
              <filter_clause>
            }
         ]
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap any (sub)query in the [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context) which is a yes/no operation where no scoring occurs:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {...}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Though `function_scores` are supposed to affect the scoring so I don't think it makes sense to disallow it in this way.